# What is another way of saying "how" in a question context?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, questions

For example, in the situation "How does a affect b?" I've come up with "In what way does a affect b?" and "What aspects of a make it affect b?" (although that has a slightly different connotation). Can anyone think of any more?

Comment: Hi Marilla, welcome to ELU. To get a clear unambiguoous answer, you need to give more context in your question. As @Mahnax's answer indicates, there are several possible interpretations of your sentence - the correct "another way of saying" depends on which meaning you want. Unless you edit the question to give that information it may get closed as "not a real question".

Answer (score 4):

- How does ...?
- By what method does ...?
- By virtue of what does ...?
- By what means ...?
- In what regard ...?
- In what sense ...?
- By what reasoning ...?
- Whereby does ...?
- In what manner does ...?
- In what way does ...?
- Which mechanism does *a* use to affect *b*?
- ...

Answer (score 3):

A short list:

- By what means does A affect B?
- In what regard does A affect B?
- In what sense does A affect B?
- By what reasoning does A affect B?

Comment: May I suggest you make this a community wiki?

Comment: @slim For what purpose?

Comment: so that your list may be extended, rather than us having a bunch of somewhat overlapping lists.

Comment: @slim Are you saying that every answer with multiple suggestions for a single-word-request or word-choice question should be CW?

Comment: If (as with Stack Overflow) the aim is to achieve a correct answer that the OP can accept, then yes. See http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/1187/3626

Comment: @slim For now, I'm leaving it. If this question attracts multiple similar answers as you suggest it will, then I might make it CW.

Comment: It's true that many answers on EL&U are not marked as community wiki when they should be. But they should be, and so should yours.

Answer (score 1):

*How* is the wastebasket interrogative.

It can refer to practically any concept that can link one idea to another.

- *How ... ???* (to represent complete bewilderment)
- *How are you?*
- *How can this possibly cause that?*
- *How does the thingummy fit on the sprocket?*

This is one reason why it is the extensible one -- when we want an adjectival or adverbial interrogative phrase, we add *how*.

- *How big is it?*
- *How easily did he do it?*

By itself, it can represent almost any adverbial phrase, and the examples given in the other answers are all adverbial phrases made into interrogatives by pied-piping. There are lots more.

Comment: Perhaps *catch-all, all-purpose*, or *multipurpose* would serve better than *wastebasket*?  If you mean like *throwaway* or *of little note*, perhaps so, but if you mean *worthless*, certainly not.

Comment: None of them, exactly. A "wastebasket category" is one in which you put all the things that don't fit elsewhere. Like the category *adverb* itself, in fact.